# Selected item returns null when another form is opened

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an edit ingredient function in a recipe app, my main form opens an "add ingredients" form that itself open  an "edit selected ingredient" form, to edit the ingredient i have selected in the array, problem is that when i want to point the selected item to get its index in the in order to replace it with an input from my "edit ingredient" form it throws me "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedItem.get returned null."

```
private void edit_ingredients_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openChange();
        }
        private void openChange()
        {
            if (ingredients_list.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                changeIngredient ingredientChange = new changeIngredient();
                ingredientChange.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an ingredient to continue");
            }
        }
        private int findItemToEdit()
        {
            string selectedItem = ingredients_list.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int elementSelected = Array.IndexOf(currIngredients, selectedItem);
            return elementSelected;
        }
        public void IngredientName(string strNewName)
        {
            string strEdit = strNewName;
            ingredientEdit(strEdit);
            
        }
        
        private void ingredientEdit(string strEdit)
        {
            int index = findItemToEdit();
            currIngredients[index] = strEdit;
            ingredients_list.Items.Add(currIngredients[index]);
        }
```

I understand it throws this exception because another form is opened, on which there's no listbox.
I tried to get its index in the array before the edit form opens, but it somehow loses the value.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you debugged the application by stepping through the code to check that the state is what you expect?

Comment: @AndrewH Yes, I have been stuck on this for hours, I checked my code and as I said I tried to bypass the problem by trying to save the position before the 2nd form opens, but the value somehow gets lost so i went back to my initial idea.
Everything works as expected, i just can't figure  out a way to fix this problem of null return, meanwhile i obviously see an item selected